# Regex - How do I match all groups of characters that both do and do not match a pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match groups of characters that both match and don't match the pattern `/\*\d*\*/g`. For example, if my string is:

`"*96* is *5* and not *547*."`

I want my matches to be `"*96*"`, `" is "`, `"*5*"`, `" and not "`, `"*547*"` and `"."`.

All the answers I've seen have involved negative lookaheads but I just can't get them to work correctly.

Comment: Do you want matches or do you want to remove them from the string? You could use split to get your matches `console.log(str.split(/\*\d*\*/g).filter(Boolean))`

Comment: I want to match everything.

Comment: Then `console.log(str.split(/(\*\d*\*)/g).filter(Boolean))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of matching, you could use your pattern inside a capturing group to keep the delimiters `(\*\d*\*)` and use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) :

```js
let str = "*96* is *5* and not *547*.";
console.log(str.split(/(\*\d*\*)/g).filter(Boolean))
```

Comment: Great solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a straight regex answer, but what about using split with a regex separator?  It will then put where the string has split in an array.

```js
var test = "*96* is *5* and not *547*.";
var splits = test.split(/\*\d*\*/g);
console.log(splits);
```